# ESQL InputLocalEnvironment data type

Tags: messagebroker, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I want to be able to access the InputLocalEnvironment within a Procedure call.

```
    CREATE FUNCTION Main() RETURNS BOOLEAN
    BEGIN
    SET OutputLocalEnvironment = InputLocalEnvironment;
    --Call Procedure doStuff
    END

    CREATE PROCEDURE doStuff ( IN inputLocalEnvironment ) RETURNS BOOLEAN
    BEGIN
    --Do Stuff with the inputLocalEnvironment
    END
```

What is the data type I should use to pass InputLocalEnvironment as the above procedure will obviously through an error.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE doStuff ( IN inputLocalEnvironment DataType)
```

If someone has a better suggestion I'm open to the idea but I need to be able to get information out of the local variables and then place them into an output.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work with the REFERENCE data type:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE doStuff (IN inputLocalEnvironment REFERENCE)
```

Comment: Thank you Attila, I was completely drawing a blank on the keyword and could not find it.